# Angular adding select values to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

I have nested loops in my project. There is a kind of schedule with shifts, locations and users. It looks like this:

```html
<div ng-controller="calendarCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="shift in shifts" ng-show="shifts.length > 1">
        <h3 class="shift_name">{{shift.shift_name}}</h3>
        <div class="flex-container flex-container-style fixed-height">
                <div ng-repeat="location in shift.locations" class="flex-item location">
                    <p class="location_name">{{location['location-name']}}</p>
                    <div>
                      <ol class="nya-bs-select" data-ng-model="location.persons" data-live-search="true" data-selected-text-format="count" multiple>
                        <li nya-bs-option="user in users group by user.group" title="{{user.person_name}}">
                          <span class="dropdown-header">{{$group}}</span> <!-- group header cannot be searched -->
                          <a>
                            <img ng-src="{{user.avatar}}">
                            <span>{{ user.person_name }}</span> <!-- this content will be search first -->
                            <span class="small">{{ user.position }}</span> <!-- if the name failed, this will be used -->
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ol>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="person in location.persons">
                        <div class="item item-divider" ng-if="firstLetter(person.position) != firstLetter(location.persons[$index-1].position)">
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media {{person['status']}}">
                          <div class="media-left">
                            <a href="#">
                              <img class="media-object" ng-src="{{person['avatar']}}">
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">{{person['person_name']}}</h4>
                            <span class="position_name">{{person['position']}}</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module("app", ["nya.bootstrap.select"]);

app.controller("calendarCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('users.json', {
            cache: true
    }).success(function (data) {
       $scope.users = data.users;
    });
    
    $http.get("day_info.json", {
                cache: true
        }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.shifts = data.shifts;
        $scope.firstLetter = function(name) {
          return name && name.charAt(0);
        }
    });
  
});
```

I need to be able to add some users from select to my model. It works, but the model is empty if there is no selected item in the list.

Here is a plunker project https://plnkr.co/edit/vCUtrf?p=preview

Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused.  What do you expect to be in the model if nothing is selected?

Comment: Well, this example is wrong maybe. All I need is to add users from select to users which are already in location. I thought that the right way is to bind my select to location model. But now There is no user from JSON. There are selected users only.

Comment: You need to push the selected users into the JSON array.  However, I can't tell from your plunker what you need exactly to give you any code sample, because I'm not sure what else the plunker is supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right I need to push the selected users to my  day_info.json. But how can I do that?

Comment: You have to create a function to do the push and add an ng-change to your select.  ng-change="myPush()"

Comment: Alright, thank you!